# Why might you use IEnumerable as a method return type or in a constructor

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I'm a beginner programmer in C# and I've just been working on an exercise that uses IEnumerable.

I think I understand the code, but I'm struggling to understand why you would ever use it this way

**Example 1**

consider the following isolated code.....

```
private List<Card> cards;

public Deck (IEnumerable<Card> initialCards)
{
    cards = new List<Card>(initialCards);
}
```

The code that creates a deck object and calls this constructor is...

```
Card[] cardArray = new Card[numberOfCards];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++)
{
    cardArray[i] = new Card((Suits)random.Next(0, 4), (Values)random.Next(0, 12));
}
deck1 = new Deck(cardArray);
```

If someone first wouldn't mind confirming my understanding below...

- We create an array of type Card and fill it with Cards
- We pass in the Card [] array to the Deck constructor when creating a Deck object. Even though the constructor argument contains a parameter of type IEnumerable, it's considered valid as array implements IEnumerable. *Is a cast occuring here?*
- The list cards is initialised with the IEnumerable argument passed in to the overloaded list constructor. *Again, is a this a cast or a conversion of some sort?*

It seems completely pointless to use IEnumerable as an intermediate type. The code still works the same, including the foreach loop that is eventually used if I change the constructor to...

```
public Deck (Card [] initialCards)
{
    cards = new List<Card>(initialCards);
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCardNames()
{
    string[] stringArray = new string[cards.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = cards[i].ToString();
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

This is a method from the same class. Again, I'm not sure why this is returned as an IEnumerable when we can still do a foreach on a string array.

**Example 3**

```
public IEnumerable<IWebElement> ElementCollection { get; set; }
```

This is very noobish but can someone explain to me what this is saying? Is it a public property of type IEnumerable? When you use an interface as a property type how is it a different to other types? e.g. string

This is used with LINQ later in the code, which I've not got to in my learning yet. Might this example suggests that if we only wish to iterate over something, IEnumerable can be used?

Many thanks,

Comment: An enumerable is a generalization of certain sequence operations - these operations include a subset of those provided by arrays. All arrays (or Lists) *implement* IEnumerable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Returning interfaces (in this case `IEnumerable`) or accepting them is one core approach in Object Oriented Programming. This mixes three of the core principles of OOP, especially **abstraction**.

In long term support application, you often make changes. At the beginning of your application you do need fixed size of `Card` collection, so you do use an array.

```
private Card[] cards;

public Deck (Card[] initialCards)
{
    cards = initialCards;
}
```

At some point you need to move on a non-fixed size of `Card` collection. So you move to a `List`

```
private List<Card> cards;

public Deck (Card [] initialCards)
{
    cards = new List<Card>(initialCards);
}
```

In one part of your application you have a `List` of `Card` too. You want to pass it to your constructor. You cannot! Even your internal structure is a `List`, your constructor is still accepting an array (`Card[]`).

You need from this external part to convert your `List` to an array. To do that you need to iterate over all of the list an create a new structure in memory - an array of cards. It could be expensive if your deck has millions of cards.

So you change your constructor to accept a `List`

```
private List<Card> cards;

public Deck (List<Card> initialCards)
{
    cards = initialCards;
}
```

At some point your application grows. You need to play a game with unique cards. One part of your application creates a `HashSet` of cards. You cannot pass it to the constructor. The damn constructor is accepting `List`'s. And if you change the constructor to accepts `HashSet`'s, you will break the logic from another part of your application that passes `List`.

You want from two parts of the application to pass either `HashSet` or `List` in the same manner, and your deck just to take this collection and assign it to the internal structure.

What you really need is to take a collection of `Cards` that can be `foreach`'d and enumerate it later for another usage. Then you just tell your other parts of the application - "Guys, just give me an object that can be enumerated. I really don't care if it's `Set`, `List` or an `Array`".

```
private IEnumerable<Card> cards;

public Deck (IEnumerable<Card> initialCards)
{
    cards = initialCards;
}
```

The same goes for the other way. It reduces complexity. You just tell your consumers, that you will give them a collection of `Card` names to enumerate. They need to list it and see some card names. They don't need to change names, add new cards or anything else.

You do not expose your implementation details. You just give the opportunity your object to be used with minimal understanding of its internal structures. This way of hiding information you may find as part of the **encapsulation**.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1**

> We create an array of type Card and fill it with Cards

Not a question, but correct.

> We pass in the Card [] array to the Deck constructor when creating a
>   Deck object. Even though the constructor argument contains a parameter
>   of type IEnumerable, it's considered valid as array implements
>   IEnumerable. Is a cast occuring here?

It's an implicit type of cast. You don't need to downcast when a type implements an interface because the type is 'of that type'. For example, you wouldn't require everyone who's speaking about the fruit Kiwi to differ between when they mean "Kiwi" and "Fruit", because Kiwi has all the properties of fruit.

> The list cards is initialised with the IEnumerable argument passed in
>   to the overloaded list constructor. Again, is a this a cast or a
>   conversion of some sort?

If you check, List contains an IEnumerable constructor. As your constructor is passed an IEnumerable no cast is required to turn an IEnumerable to another IEnumerable.

> It seems completely pointless to use IEnumerable as an intermediate type. The code still works the same, including the foreach loop that is eventually used if I change the constructor to...

```
public Deck (Card [] initialCards)
{
    cards = new List<Card>(initialCards);
}
```

It's not pointless, changing the constructor to this would break any code that tries to send Lists to the constructor instead.

**Example 2**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCardNames()
{
    string[] stringArray = new string[cards.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = cards[i].ToString();
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

> This is a method from the same class. Again, I'm not sure why this is
>   returned as an IEnumerable when we can still do a foreach on a string
>   array.

Usually you'd put methods like this in an interface and guarantee every implementation can return IEnumerable. Often with IEnumerables you can defer the calculation using yield and clever logic while calling GetCardNames() as Array would directly enforce the calculation to happen. There are numerous reasons to use IEnumerable, but often they point to some kind of "guarantee" that you can't guarantee Arrays conform to.

**Example 3**

```
public IEnumerable<IWebElement> ElementCollection { get; set; }
```

> This is very noobish but can someone explain to me what this is
>   saying? Is it a public property of type IEnumerable? When you use an
>   interface as a property type how is it a different to other types?
>   e.g. string
>
> This is used with LINQ later in the code, which I've not got to in my
>   learning yet. Might this example suggests that if we only wish to
>   iterate over something, IEnumerable can be used?

It is a public IEnumerable property as you have said with a default backer and etc. IEnumerable guarantees it can be iterated over, which is quite a strong guarantee as it allows searching and more things. Just because you can iterate over it doesn't mean the items are contiguous or anything else so implementations may vary. This is one of the strengths of interfaces.

Also different spots in your code can assign different types to the IEnumerable property. Some may send it lists, others may send it arrays. Also to defer the calculation to when it needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are very thorough. Here's a slightly shorter one:

An array, a list, and other collection types all implement `IEnumerable`. Declaring a method argument as `IEnumerable` indicates that the method doesn't "care" what the actual type is as long as it implements `IEnumerable`.

If your method is going to `for...each` through a collection, then why specify that it needs to be an array or a list? There's no need to be more specific when you can be less specific.

It's also a way of telling what the method expects to do with the parameter passed to it. If a method takes a parameter of `IEnumerable<T>` it's in effect saying, "I'm just going to take your collection and enumerate through it. I'm not going to add or remove items."

If the parameter is a `List<T>` or an `IList<T>` then the method that receives it could add or delete items.

Less common, for for the sake of illustration - if you pass an array to a method, that method could change the sort order of the array. (To be honest that's not a possibility I'm usually concerned about.)

Granted, specifying those types can't absolutely enforce those behaviors, but it's a way for a method to communicate its behavior. You add to a list. You enumerate an `IEnumerable`.